# How can I configure Chrome so that it doesn't display "the extension [X] was automatically disabled" when starting?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I configure Chrome so that it doesn't display "the extension [X] was automatically disabled" when starting?

I don't want to see the following message:

[image]

I use the latest version of Google Chrome, i.e. Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Do you want the extensions disabled or not, or do you only care about not showing this pop up?

Comment: @music2myear I don't care about not showing this pop up.

Comment: are the extensions downloaded from chrome webstore?

Comment: @Sanu_012 pretty sure yes.

Comment: Is this the latest version of Google Chrome?

Comment: @Sanu_012 yes, Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)
.

Comment: I think this has to do something with the permissions of those extensions. Does this happen to all extensions you try to install?

Comment: @Sanu_012 no just a few ones. The message doesn't appear during the installation, but when chrome launches.

Comment: yeah, this problem seems little odd. Never heard of something like that. Did you ever try installing those extensions in another pc just to cross check that the extensions work fine?

Comment: @Sanu_012 I haven't tried. I don't need them for now, so I'm ok with them being disabled.